# Bison Flex calculator and boolean interpreter

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, interpreter, flex-lexer

I'm doing a bison/flex interpreter that need to compare numbers (<,>), do the aritmethics basic operations, and boolean like AND OR XOR NOT.

The first step was comparing two numbers and the code was fine to that. Now I apply the changes needed to find if a number is prime or not, and the code just return Error.

I tried to change the code several times but with no changes

There is the code of the lexer:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for atof() */
#include "test.tab.h"
%}

%%

[0-1]+  { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUM; }
[false]   { yylval = 0; return FALSE; }
[true]   { yylval = 1; return TRUE; }
[and]   { yylval = atoi(yytext); return AND; }
[xor]   { yylval = atoi(yytext); return XOR; }
[not]   { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NOT; }




[ \t\n]+        /* whitespace */
.       return yytext[0];
```

and here is the .y

```
%{
  #define YYSTYPE int

  #include <math.h>     
  #include <stdio.h>    
  #include <stdlib.h>   

  int yylex(void);
  void yyerror(char*);
%}

%token NUM
%token BOOLEAN
%left '<' '>' '=' '!=' 'mod' 'div' AND NOT XOR TRUE FALSE

%%
program:       /* empty */
              | programa command
;

command:        ';'
              | expression ';'       //{ printf("%i\n", $1);}
;



expression:          NUM                     { $$ = $1; }

             | expression '<' expression          { $$ = $1 < $3;
                  if ($$==1)
                 printf("TRUE \n");
                  else {
                    printf("FALSE \n");
                  }
                }
             | izraz '>' izraz          { $$ = $1 > $3;
                  if ($$==1)
                 printf("TRUE \n");
                  else {
                    printf("FALSE \n");
                  }
                }
             | izraz '=' izraz          { $$ = $1 == $3;
                  if ($$==1)
                 printf("TRUE \n");
                  else {
                    printf("FALSE \n");
                  }
                }
             | izraz '!=' izraz         { $$ = $1 != $3;
                  if ($$==1)
                 printf("TRUE \n");
                  else {
                    printf("FALSE \n");
                  }
                }
;
%%
main() {
  yyparse();
}

void yyerror(char *s) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", s);
}
```

That code was okay to compare two natural numbers, but now just return the error and i'm really lost now

Answer (score 1):

There are some serious issues with your scanner and parser.

1. `[false]` does not mean what you think it does.

   You seem to think that it means something lke "match  the keyword `false`". That pattern would be simply `false`.

   What `[false]` means is "match exactly one character if it is one of `a`, `e`,  `f`, `l` or `s`". `[…]` is a *character class*, which defines a set of possible characters.

   Perhaps it would be worth reading an introduction to regular expressions, but also definitely read the [flex documentation](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns), because there are some differences with other regex libraries.
2. Most of your parse rules refer to `izraz`, which you seem to have translated in one place to `expression`. I don't know if this is a copying error or if your actual source file looks like that.
3. `'!='` is not a valid single-character token, and there is no way your scanner can recognise the two-character token.

Beyond that, since you have provided no description whatsoever of the actual problem you encounter, it is not easy to provide a solution. Fix the obvious problems and if you continue to have a problem, create a new question with complete details: a compilable program, a sample input, and a description of how the result differs from what you expect.